# There is no any output in a running Drupal, what's the problem?

Tags: php, drupal

Apache, Mysql, PHP is running well.

Suddenly all the page just display nothing, what's the problem? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Despite the info you provided is insufficient to make an accurate answer, there are a set of reasons that may cause that to happen, take a look here: [White Screen of Death (WSOD)](http://drupal.org/node/158043)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the WSOD:
http://drupal.org/node/158043

Answer (score 1):

Check your Apache log errors on the server. It will tell you what happened.